# Where are adapter passwords stored in BizTalk?

Tags: binding, passwords, export, single-sign-on, biztalk

When exporting bindings in BizTalk, passwords are not included but I guess they exist in the database. Can anyone pin-point me to the location of passwords in the database? Or any other way of fetching the passwords used in receive locations and send ports?

In the end I hope to create a solution where the bindings including passwords are backed up daily, and using deployment framework or manually adding passwords in the binding files is from my point of view not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

BizTalk stores credentials securely in the Enterprise Single Sign-On database, using the Enterprise SSO service. They are encrypted, which will prevent you from extracting the passwords.

You can find more details about the Enterprise SSO functionality of BizTalk in the answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1772663/whats-entsso-for-in-biztalk-server).

The best way to backup the configuration is to [backup the various BizTalk and EnterpriseSSO databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560767.aspx), along with the [Master Secret](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559192.aspx).